# Is it possible to retain a variable in memory (RAM) in PHP?

Tags: php, database, performance, caching, cpu-usage

I'm studying high-performance coding for websites in PHP, and this idea popped into my mind:

We know that accessing a database uses a significant amount of CPU usage, so we cache such data, saving it to the HDD. But I was wondering, can't it rest in the RAM of the server, so I can access it **even more** faster?

Comment: Keep in mind that operating systems cache the files in ram for you too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to check out memcached:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcache.php

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that it stored it there.

Answer (score 1):

PHP normally comes with [APC](https://www.php.net/apc/) as a bytecode cache. You can also use it as a local cache. If you need something in a distributed/clustered environment, then [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/) (plus possibly [beanstalkd](http://xph.us/software/beanstalkd/)) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

XCache, eaccelerator, apc and memcache allow you to save items to semi persistent memory (you don't necessarily know when an item will expire in most cases).  It isn't the same as a database, more like a key/value list.  The downside being that it requires a third party library, so you might be a bit limited depending on your environment.

I think you might be able to get the same effect using shared memory (via php's shmop_ functions).  But I have never used them or know if they are included with php's library so someone feel free to bash me or edit out this mention.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is *ANY* good, then it will already do so.  But of course, it may be the case that your server is serving a few thousand other tasks besides yours as well, meaning you don't have that server's cache all for yourself.

And if there really are a few thousand others being served besides you, then the probability just gets higher that there is at least one nutcase among those thousands of others, who is doing something that he really shouldn't be doing but that the server has not been programmed to detect, not been programmed to stop, but just been programmed to try and make the best of it, at the expense of availability of resources for the x999 "responsible" users.